# You've flagged this message as spam, inappropriate, or offensive - but I didn't

Tags: bug, flags, chat, notifications

Why is that the title of the flag icon shows me *"You've flagged this message as spam, inappropriate, or offensive"* when I didn't flagged the post at all.

[image: Flag]

All I did was, deemed the flag as invalid, though user was bit harsh but he was correct.

---

Also, something's fishy with the flag count, I did see a flag notification, the count was saying **0** but the flag had **1** in queue ...

[image]

Still it's the same for me as far as count of the flags is concerned, am on Chrome 32, Windows 7

[image]

---

Edit : I think the flag count issue is now fixed

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Message 17683586, counter-flag (i.e. "invalid", aka "the text is ok, don't burninate"), Mr. Alien, 2014-07-14 10:42:42.283 (UTC); basically, the dialog is simply including your counter-flag in this panel. Perhaps it is poorly worded: what it really means is "you've cast your vote already".

Comment: Ok, so we should reword that nicely and any idea about the count? It shows 0 and I can see the flag in the queue ...